# From SVD, $X = U \Sigma V^\top$, how to get eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

SVD says $X = U \Sigma V^\top$ and it is used for PCA (Principal Component Analysis).

In my understanding, Principal Components are eigenvectors of $X$. If so, where are eigenvectors? Is it in $U$ or $V$?

Suppose there is a matrix $X$ of shape $(N, D) = (1000, 784)$ having $1000$ images and $D$ is the image size $(28 \times 28)$, from where can I get the eigenvectors of $X$?

Alternatively, if the matrix is shaped as $(D, N) = (784, 1000)$ as in [Singular Value Decomposition (SVD): Matrix Approximation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xy3QyyhiuY4&t=154s) to hold the same $1000$ images, from where can I get the eigenvectors of $X$? In the video, $X$ is sequence of face images where $X_i$ is a face image.

[image: Screenshot from video on SVD.]

Comment: Note: an eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$ of a matrix $A$ is a nonzero vector such that $A\mathbf{v} = \lambda\mathbf{v}$ for some scalar $\lambda$ and since the vectors on either side of the equation must be the same size, $A$ has to be a **square** matrix.

Comment: However, we can interpret the left-singular vectors (cols of $U$) as eigenvectors of $MM^\top$ and the right-singular vectors (cols of $V$ or rows of $V^\top$) as eigenvectors of $M^\top M$. In either case, the eigen*values* of $M M^\top$ or $M^\top M$ are $\sigma_1^2, \dots, \sigma_m^2$, where $\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_m$ are the singular values (diagonal entries in $\Sigma$). 

You can read more, including one-line calculations of the above facts, [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Singular_value_decomposition#Relation_to_eigenvalue_decomposition).

Comment: Thanks so much @SammyBlack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Principal components are not eigenvectors of $X$, but of $X^T X$ (it doesn't even make sense to talk of eigenvalues of non-square matrices).

From your
SVD you can compute
$$ X^TX = (U\Sigma V^T)^TU \Sigma V^T = V \Sigma U^T U \Sigma V^T = V \Sigma^2 V^T,$$
so the principal compontents are the columns of $V$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to understand, if X is a column order matrix, the covariance matrix is still $C = X^TX$? For instance to find the covariance between English score and Math score of N students, we need a covariance matrix of shape (D, D) where D=2. But if X shape is (D, N), $X^TX$ gives (N, N) matrix?

Comment: @mon No, what i said applies when the rows of $X$ represent an entry. If its the opposite you should work with $XX^T$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the follow up.